# Cannot connect to socket io server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have bot socket IO client and server running. I want to have client communicate with server.

#### Server initialization

```
this.http_server = net.createServer();
// this didn't work too. Exxentially socket io does not work at all
//   this.io = io.listen(typeof port == "number" ? port : process.env.PORT);
console.log("[ManagementServer] Attaching socket IO to HTTP server.");
this.io = io(this.http_server);
/// The port does open
this.http_server.listen(typeof port == "number" ? port : process.env.PORT,
    () => {
        console.log('[ManagementServer] IO HTTP server listening on port', this.http_server.address().port)
    });
/// The connection listener is triggered, but IO doesn't bother 
/// replying or something
this.http_server.on("connection", (req, res) => {
    console.log("[ManagementServer] Connection received, but IO ignores it.")
});
// Never happens
this.io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    this.connection(socket);
})
```

#### Client initialization

```
const srvurl = "http://" + this.remoteAddr + ":" + this.remotePort;

console.log("[UDP_socketio] Connecting to server: ", srvurl)
this.client = socketioclient(srvurl);

this.client.once("connect", () => {
    console.log("[UDP_socketio] Connected to remote server, identificating.")
    this.sendIdentification();
});

this.client.on("error", () => {
    console.error("[UDP_socketio] Socket IO connection error.")
});
```

#### Socket IO debug output

I enabled debug, but socket IO debug output is not very useful anyway:

```
[ManagementServer] Attaching socket IO to HTTP server.
  socket.io:server initializing namespace / +0ms
  socket.io-parser encoding packet {"type":0,"nsp":"/"} +0ms
  socket.io-parser encoded {"type":0,"nsp":"/"} as 0 +1ms
  socket.io:server creating engine.io instance with opts {"serveClient":false,"path":"/","initialPacket":["0"]} +3ms
[ManagementServer] IO HTTP server listening on port 80
[UDP_socketio] Connecting to server:  http://127.0.0.1:80
  socket.io-client:url parse http://127.0.0.1:80 +0ms
  socket.io-client new io instance for http://127.0.0.1:80 +0ms
  socket.io-client:manager readyState closed +0ms
  socket.io-client:manager opening http://127.0.0.1:80 +1ms
  engine.io-client:socket creating transport "polling" +0ms
  engine.io-client:polling polling +0ms
  engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr poll +0ms
  engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr open GET: http://127.0.0.1/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MEuBb8c&b64=1 +1ms
  engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr data null +0ms
  engine.io-client:socket setting transport polling +10ms
  socket.io-client:manager connect attempt will timeout after 20000 +12ms
  socket.io-client:manager readyState opening +1ms
[ManagementServer] Connection received, but IO ignores it.
  socket.io-client:manager connect attempt timed out after 20000 +20s
  engine.io-client:socket socket close with reason: "forced close" +20s
  engine.io-client:polling transport not open - deferring close +20s
  engine.io-client:socket socket closing - telling transport to close +0ms
  socket.io-client:manager connect_error +2ms
  socket.io-client:manager cleanup +0ms
  socket.io-client:manager will wait 1178ms before reconnect attempt +1ms
  socket.io-client:manager attempting reconnect +1s
  socket.io-client:manager readyState closed +0ms
  socket.io-client:manager opening http://127.0.0.1:80 +1ms
```

Notice that the listener for connection that I added triggers, but socket IO does nothing.

What did not help so far:

- Removing the `connection` listener from the `this.http_server`
- Changing port used for testing
- Increasing delay after which client tries to connect
- Reading socket.io documentation. It's confusing, incomplete, inaccurate and inconsistent.

What could make socket IO ignore all connections like this? Maybe the server is listening for request from different paths? If that's the case, how to check what path is IO listening on?

Comment: Remove the `path: "/",` from your server initialization and let socket.io use its natural path.  You do not need to supply a path on the client when connecting.  It will add its own natural path.  If you specify no path on both client and server, it will use its own default path and that part of the code will work.

Comment: @jfriend00 No that doesn't help. I actually added the path because it didn't work, so I wanted to ensure a valid path.

Comment: Well, it isn't going to work with the path like you have it.  Remove it from the server and then you can get to the next problem that is blocking you.

Comment: *socket.io* works with http/s servers like *express* (layer 7). *net* seems to be a TCP server (layer 4). Have you checked they can work together?

Comment: @RaphaMex That's it - I used TCP server instead of HTTP one. Could you post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*socket.io* works with **http/s** servers like express (layer 7).

*net* is a **TCP** server (layer 4).

So they are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're inserting the socket.io.js file into your client code and using it. If you try to create your own WebSocket on the client-side, you'll probably run into problems.

Do something like this for your server:

```
var app = require('express').createServer()
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

and something like this for the HTML file you're serving:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Make sure you're serving /socket.io/socket.io.js from your webserver dir. Then all you have to do is watch your console login to the web browser's Developer environment from the Options or with Firebug when you go to the page.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on your explanation please could you a bit clearer cause I'm facing a similar problem